# Robotium: How do I wait for loading to complete before proceeding?

Tags: java, android, junit, robotium

I want to write a Robotium/Junit test for an android app.  At certain steps, I want my test to wait until the spinning loading symbol disappears off the screen.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are different ways in which you can do that. In Robotium there are a lot of different waitFor methods that you can use. In your case you can use:

```
solo.waitForDialogToClose() //waits for the dialog to close
solo.waitForActivity() // if there is a activity change
solo.waitForText() //if a certain text appears after the loading is done
solo.waitForView() //if a certain view is shown after the load screen is done.
```

Please see the [Robotium API Documentation](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumAPIDocumentation) for more waitFor methods in Robotium.

Comment: Thanks... it seems to work but takes longer than I expected when I use this command:

`solo.waitForActivity(solo.getCurrentActivity().toString());`

Comment: @Renas If i want to wait for horizontal progress bar means, how could i use these methods?

Comment: solo.waitForDialogToClose() will not work if u have alert dialog immediately after progressdialog, robotium will will wait for alert dialog to close.